# TouchableOpacity execute without touching

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have three TouchableOpacities which i want to execute defferent functions when user touched.but as now after start the app the functions in side touchable opacities run without touching.they are executing infinitely.How can i solve this.

TouchableOpacities

```
  <View style={styles.headerButtonMain}>
                  <View style={styles.headerButton}>
                          <TouchableOpacity style={{
                              marginRight: 25
                          }} onPress={this.loadListData()}>
                              <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./img/imgCase.png')}/>
                          </TouchableOpacity>

                          <TouchableOpacity style={{
                              marginRight: 25
                          }} onPress={this.loadCustomerData()}>
                              <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./img/imgCall.png')}/>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          <TouchableOpacity style={{
                              marginRight: 25
                          }} onPress={this._onPressButton}>
                              <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./img/imgCase.png')}/>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={{
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: '#fff',
                      marginLeft: 15,
                      marginTop: 38,
                      marginBottom: 20
                  }}>My Cases</Text>
              </View>
```

render function

```
render() {
          if(this.viewCaseData === true){
          var caseList =   <View >
                <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}></ListView>

            </View>
    }else{
          var caseList =  <ScrollView style={{
                marginLeft: 10,
                marginRight: 10
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    marginBottom: 10,
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Search</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View >
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{
                            marginLeft: 320,
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                            backgroundColor: '#DA4336'
                        }}>
                            <Text style={{
                                color: '#fff'
                            }}>Search</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Customer Category</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Customer Category Type</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Customer Code Type</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Customer Code</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>BranchLocation</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Title</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Full Name</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Initials</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Lastname</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Preferred Name</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>DateOf Birth</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Gender</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Mother Maiden Name</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Nationality</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Religon</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Marital Status</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Preferred Language</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Mobile01</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Mobile02</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.seperator}/>
                <View style={styles.textMainView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Email</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textDetail}>value</Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
          }

            return (
              <View >
                  <View style={styles.headerView}>

                      <View >
                          <View style={styles.circle}>
                              <Text style={{
                                  fontSize: 40,
                                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                                  color: '#fff',
                                  marginLeft: 18
                              }}>A</Text>
                          </View>

                          <Text style={{
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: '#fff',
                              marginLeft: 15,
                              marginTop: 5,
                              marginBottom: 20
                          }}>User Name</Text>
                      </View>

                      <View style={styles.headerButtonMain}>
                          <View style={styles.headerButton}>
                                  <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                      marginRight: 25
                                  }} onPress={this.loadListData()}>
                                      <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./img/imgCase.png')}/>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>

                                  <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                      marginRight: 25
                                  }} onPress={this.loadCustomerData()}>
                                      <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./img/imgCall.png')}/>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                  <TouchableOpacity style={{
                                      marginRight: 25
                                  }} onPress={this._onPressButton}>
                                      <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./img/imgCase.png')}/>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                          </View>
                          <Text style={{
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: '#fff',
                              marginLeft: 15,
                              marginTop: 38,
                              marginBottom: 20
                          }}>My Cases</Text>
                      </View>

                  </View>
                  <View>
                      <View>
                          <ColoredFab>
                              <Image pointerEvents="none" source={require('./img/plus_white.png')}/>
                          </ColoredFab>
                      </View>

    {caseList}
                  </View>

              </View>

            );
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `onPress` expects a function, but you directly invoke the function, so it has the result of your function as value. You may either do

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.loadListData.bind(this)}>
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.loadListData()}>
```

The first one binds the this (if you don't use it within the function `this.loadListData` would be sufficient and the second one wraps your call in an arrow function.

Comment: hi.can you help me one more question.as now my view didnt scrolling.i cant seen my buttons and text on bottom of the view.how can i solve this

Comment: You need to use a ScrollView

Comment: i added the scrollview like this `<ScrollView ref='scrollView' contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}} style={{
                marginLeft: 10,
                marginRight: 10,
                flex:1
            }}>` but it wont worked.i post new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532729/react-native-view-wont-scroll can you help me