# TouchableOpacity deletes without touching

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

So I want to use TouchableOpacity in order to press on the component and delete data from the Firebase, but instead it's deletes everything in my firebase if I do

```
OnPress= {this.DeleteAds(item.key)}
```

I tried follow instructions in here [TouchableOpacity execute without touching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531899/touchableopacity-execute-without-touching)  but now the button doesn't do anything.

Here is the code :

```
export default class Ads extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ 
    adlist:[],
    } }

   
 DeleteAds = (key)=>{
  firebase.database().ref('/ads/'+key).remove();
  navigation.navigate("Home")
  
  console.log(key)

};
  

    componentDidMount(){
      firebase.database().ref('/ads').on('value', (snapshot) =>{
        var list = []
        snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
         list.push({
          key:child.key,
          title:child.val().title,
          details: child.val().details
        })


      })

     this.setState({adlist:list})
    
    })
   }
   render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container_3}>
          <Text> Ads</Text>
        </View>
        
         <FlatList 
            data={this.state.adlist}
            keyExtractor={(item)=>item.key}
            renderItem={({item})=>{
               return(
                <TouchableOpacity  OnPress ={()=>this.DeleteAds(item.key)}>
                <View style={styles.container_2}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_style1}>{item.title}</Text>
                     <Text>{item.details}</Text>
               
                </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
               )}}/>
       </View>
    )}
  }
```

I will be grateful if you help to fix the issue.

Comment: Do you see the console.log when you press ?

Comment: The console.log doesn't show anything when I press. Only if I do OnPress= {this.DeleteAds(item.key)} prints the all the keys in the database and then proceeds to delete them all

Comment: its onPress not OnPress change that and it should work :)

Comment: It's worked! Thank you for rescuing for the second time ^-^